# redirect old url to new url but old url shown into new url

Tags: php, .htaccess

Open: `zalora-kupon-kode-diskon-voucher-promosi/`

result: `http://www.situskupon.com/toko/zalora_indonesia-2.html?zalora-kupon-kode-diskon-voucher-promosi`

you will find old url after ?

what is wrong?

this is my htaccess:

```html
# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexOptions +Charset=UTF-8
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteEngine on

RedirectMatch 301 zalora-kupon-kode-diskon-voucher-promosi/ http://www.situskupon.com/toko/zalora_indonesia-2.html
RedirectMatch 301 lazada-kupon-kode-diskon-voucher-promosi/ http://www.situskupon.com/toko/lazada_indonesia-3.html
RedirectMatch 301 hostgator-kupon-kode-diskon-voucher-promosi/ http://www.situskupon.com/toko/hostgator-5.html

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^situskupon\.com [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]

## This should be a normal page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)-(\d+).html$ index.php?pages=$2 [QSA,L]

## This should be a page from the theme
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)-(\d+).html$ index.php?$1=$3 [QSA,L]

## This should be a page from theme 2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+).html$ index.php?tpage=$1 [QSA,L]

## This should be a plugin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+).(php|html|xml)$ index.php?$1=$2&ext=$3 [QSA,L]

ErrorDocument 403 /index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
ErrorDocument 500 /index.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing mod_alias (`RedirectMatch`) and mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`) directives and there is a conflict. Different modules run at different times, which is not necessarily the same order as the directives appear in your .htaccess file.

What happens is that the following internal rewrite triggers first, since this also matches the URL:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

Then your `RedirectMatch` triggers later, resulting in the redirect you are seeing.

**Solution...** don't mix rewrites/redirects from both modules. Change the mod_alias redirects to use mod_rewrite instead:

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^zalora-kupon-kode-diskon-voucher-promosi/$ http://www.situskupon.com/toko/zalora_indonesia-2.html [R=301,L]
```

Note that you will need to clear your browser cache, since `301` redirects are cached. It can be easier to first test with `302` (temporary) redirects for this reason.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. To indicate the question is "resolved" please mark the answer as "accepted" (click the tick on the left). This then takes the question out of the unanswered question queue. Much appreciated, thanks.